# How can I make Vb.Net Login form allow multiple users to login using passwords stored in a .DAT file

Tags: vb.net

I have a login form designed with VB 2008. A user can log in by selecting either Admin or Guest from a dropdown list in combobox. Then enter a password which must match with passwords stored with a corresponding usernames in a .DAT file.

[screenshot showing usernames and passwords stored in .DAT file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zTBB.png)

The second username Guest and password which is "passwordG" on the file is working while the first username Admin and password which is "passwordG is not working.

```
Public Class frmlogin
Dim user_name As String
Dim pass_word As String
Dim counter As Byte
Dim attempts As Integer = 0

Private Sub login_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    cmbUsername.Items.Add("Admin")
    cmbUsername.Items.Add("Guest")
    FileOpen(1, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\users.DAT", OpenMode.Input)
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Input(1, user_name)
        Input(1, pass_word)
    Loop
    FileClose(1)
```

Please I need help on how to make this work. That how to make the program accept the passwords. Is the code not correct or inadequate or the passwords are not correctly stored in the `.DAT` file?

Please I need your help. Thank you.

Comment: Timers don't work like that.  Use the tick event.  It's not clear what the problem is.  Do favor .Net version of file reading, not the old VB3 version.

Comment: I have included a screenshot of the usernames and passwords above. Please check the screenshot and see if it is how is supposed to be saved. See the content of the users.DAT file here   -  "Admin","passwordA"
"Guest","passwordG"
The first line contains Admin and passwordA, the second line contains Guest and passwordG. Please check if it is correct.

Comment: Your code is looping through the file, but only setting the user_name and pass_word on the last loop.  You probably want a list.

Comment: @apprentice01 As you can see, 2008 as *you stated* in your question is very old compared to the current year of 2021. I think it was reasonable for me to ask if you were trying to modernize old code. You are of course entitled to alienate people who would otherwise help you find a solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a plain text file. Otherwise, we will have to strip off the quotaion marks.

```
Admin,passwordA
Guest,passwordG
```

Since I close the Login form, be sure the Application property for shutdown is set as follows:

[image]

```
Private GuestPassword As String
Private AdminPassword As String

Private Sub login_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Fill the combo box
    cmbUsername.Items.Add("Admin")
    cmbUsername.Items.Add("Guest")
    'one of the .net methods to read a file, returns an array of lines in the file
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("user.txt")
    'Split by the comma, the first line into and array
    Dim splits = lines(0).Split(","c)
    'The second element of this array holds the Admin password
    AdminPassword = splits(1)
    splits = lines(1).Split(","c)
    GuestPassword = splits(1)
End Sub

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    If cmbUserName.Text = "Admin" AndAlso AdminPassword = txtPassword.Text Then
        'Show the Admin form
    ElseIf cmbUserName.Text = "Guest" AndAlso GuestPassword = txtPassword.Text Then
        'Show the guest form
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, no match")
    End If
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

We will use a `Dictionary` to store the users in memory. This provides a very fast lookup.

A Dictionary contains key / value pairs. Notice in the Form load we fill the `Dictionary` with password as `Key` and user type as the `Value`.

Be very careful with spaces. There shouldn't be any in the text file or the text box. You might want to add `.Trim` as a precaution.

In the button click we retrieve the `userType` by searching for the key provided by the user. This is surrounded by a `Try` block because if the key is not found an exception will be thrown.

```
Private UsersDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("users.txt")
    For Each line In lines
        Dim splits = line.Split(","c)
        UsersDictionary.Add(splits(1), splits(0))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim userType As String
    Try
        userType = UsersDictionary.Item(TextBox1.Text)
    Catch ex As System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you are not a registered user.")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    If userType = "Admin" Then
        'open the admin form
    Else
        'open the user form
    End If
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @Mary. However, I'm looking at a situation whereby even if there are 50 users, the program will be able to recognize their passwords from the .DAT or .TXT file without declaring username and password variables for each user and which will make the code too long. Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: @apprentice01 Does each user have their own password? The first entry on each line is Admin or Guest followed by a comma then the password? So, there is no actual username?

Comment: Thank you very much, you really tried. Yes, each user has their own password assigned to them and stored in the text file. So when they try to log in, the program scans through the text file to match their username with their password. I will try it out and now and see if it works. Just seeing the edit now.